# Adding more than one legend in QGIS Print Composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend, printing, classification

I'm using QGIS 2.8.4 and I can't seem to figure out adding more than one legend to my Print Composer. Say I want a larger map and then an inset map -- showing perhaps a different classification/color scheme -- on the same page of my Print Composer. For whatever reason, despite checking the lock button(s), my "locked" legend will change according to whatever my original Q map shows. Therefore, if I want to add two legends, I'm really just adding the most-recent one and duplicating it.

I've tried every possibility of the locked buttons/cache/etc.

Comment: how are you displaying 2 different maps with 2 different renderings on the same layer? That sounds like it wouldn't work though...

Comment: I can "lock" the first map, ensuring that it's like an image displayed on the Print Composer. Then, I make whatever alterations I feel like in the original Q document and I add a "new" map. The problem is that for whatever reason, the legend for the first map appears like it's locked - but then, as soon as I make the alterations (in this case, change the classification scheme color), the legend changes as well.

Answer (score 2):

At least in QGIS 2.12 this can be done by setting what map to populate the legend from in the legen item properties. In the Map dropdown box.

[image]

Comment: Yes, in 2.8.4, that option exists as well... It just doesn't actually work - just refers to the most-recently-created map. I'm wondering if this is a bug but if so, I'm sure others must have the same issue!

Comment: Works withou issue for me in QGIS 2.12.0.

Answer (score 2):

I think the key is to make sure both:

- Map has 'lock layers for map item' and 'lock layer styles for map item' **checked**
- Legend has 'Auto-update' **unchecked**

Here is a print composer where the top (pink) map is set as described above, and the 2nd map is being drawn from the same layer as the 1st map:

[image]

Comment: OP: Thanks for the reply, mapBaker. Unfortunately, I tried that (both with and without locking the maps and legends in the "Items" window above "Items properties") -- it still, for whatever reason, doesn't work. I know that adding multiple legends to a single Print Composer has worked for me in the past but I used a different version of Q. I'm wondering if that's the issue here.

Comment: @hilldawg-co do you have any data you can share?

Comment: Select the legend in the print composer. Then In the "Layout" tab under 'General Settings' ensure you have the correct 'Reference Map' set.